# Webparts asp.net

Tags: asp.net

What are the disadvantages to using webparts in asp.net?  Are they losing their popularity?
I was planning on creating a user defined Dashboard and was thinking of using Webparts, is this the way to go or is there another way of doing customisable dashboards these days? I would prefer not to have to use a 3rd party product.

Answer (score 0):

To me, webparts are more of a sharepoint thing these days.
Other than that, with some design you can get all you need with user controls and some classes of your own to get common functionality and layout sorted out.

Say you have a base class called  DashboardWidget that inherits from WebControl here you could define a overridable method

ProcessDataSource -> executes a query to a database or service and formats the results for presentation

And in the prerender method (or something similar along the asp.net lifecycle) you call ProcessDataSource (you could use the DataSource property most controls already have).

Then you inherit from DashboardWidget to make your controls and in the render method you override ProcessDataSource to get the info the way you need and the Render method to setup what to display.

Ideally you should define your own data source class to have a single place to define where to connect, how, credentials, etc..

As for the layout, newer versions of asp.net include several layout option you may use (and there is always pure html if you want)

I'm shooting from the hip a bit here, but that's a way to do it without involving webparts, that to me, are not that popular outside of sharepoint.

Hope anything of this helps